# Force Munin email notifications only on status change, not on update

Tags: linux, munin

I got Munin to notify me with email if certain values goes above my thresholds. This works very well and I am happy with it. However, there is a small glitch. If any of my values is in critical or warning state and Munin sends me notification about it, then on the next Munin update run I again receive the same notification, regardless that there is no change in the status. I found out that Munin run updates by default every 5 minutes.

Is there a way to make/force Munin to send single emails only on status change (i.e. first email for critical values, second for back to normal, not critical-critical-...-critical-normal)?

Comment: In nagios, I use retry_check_interval per active/passive check.  I am not familiar with Munin, but hope this points you in the right direction.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Sounds like you have alway_send set in munin.conf.  Try commenting out the [`contact.you.always_send`](http://munin-monitoring.org/wiki/munin.conf#Globaldirectives) line and it should work like you want it to.